# MediaType of Png. HTTP request

Tags: java, testing, web, spring-boot, content-type

I've a web app with some static content. For example, I've an image  published in `http://localhost/images/Head.png`.

Now, I'm doing a Http request to this image.

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> entity = new TestRestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost/images/Head.png", byte[].class);`
```

And I want to know which content has this entity. It should be `image/png`, but it isn't. I get an exception here:

```
 assertEquals("Wrong content type:\n" + entity.getHeaders().getContentType(),
              MediaType.valueOf("image/png"), entity.getHeaders().getContentType());`
```

Which content type should I be?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your code in a public repo? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: You can look it [here](https://github.com/Santi-7/hello/blob/master/src/test/java/es/unizar/webeng/hello/SystemTests.java)

Comment: Why the code that you refer is commented? In addition, which is the output of the JUnit test? Even, why you not print the value of the content type in the screen. If you discover the solution please answer this question yourself and mark it as closed!

Comment: It's commented becuase of debugging process.  The output is `es.unizar.webeng.hello.SystemTests > testHead FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at SystemTests.java:135`. This means, content type is not equal to `image/png`. I tried to print the value of the content, but nothing is printed (I think cause the way I'm checking it).

Comment: please, keep updated your public repo in order to check what is going on!

Comment: Of course, I've just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run

```
$ gradle check
```

The console reports something as follows

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at:
  (...)/hello-master/build/reports/tests/index.html

BUILD FAILED
```

If you open that file with a browser you can see this:

[image]

If you click on *System Tests* you can see

[image]

That means that the expected content type is *image/png;charset=UTF-8*. This content type is not wrong but quirk. This is because Spring Boot is being forced by default to add the configured charset to the content type. You can set the property of `spring.http.encoding.force` to `false` in `application.properties` and thus the returned content type will be *image/png*. Be careful, as this settings can modify the behaviour existing tests.

Comment: It worked! Thank's for the debug advices and for solving it.